# Code to Unfilter data from all sheets present in the Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of worksheets with only one table in each worksheet. I want to run a code that will unfilter/show all the data of all worksheet. so far i have written below code but it is not giving me the desire result.

```
dim ws1 as worksheet
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws1 In Worksheets
If ws1.FilterMode = True Then ws1.ShowAllData
Next ws1
On Error GoTo 0
```

Kindly review the above code and ammend.

Thanks
Salman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to tackle this from the Range.Hidden Property point of view as well as the [Worksheet.ShowAllData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197246.aspx) method. aspect. Data may have been hidden by other means than [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx).

```
Dim w As Long

For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Worksheets(w)
        .UsedRange.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    End With
Next w
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AutoFilterMode` property..

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws1 In Worksheets
If ws1.AutoFilterMode = True Then ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
Next ws1
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Well it may be filtered in different ways..you can make a `breakpoint` in your code at `If ws1.FilterMode = True` and run it then see its value is true or not in a filtered sheet..if yes then **may be** `If ws1.FilterMode = True Then ws1.FilterMode = False` will works

Comment: still now working. i have data in tables which needs to be unfiltered.

Comment: OK founded..it works only for excel 2013 and later..according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821903.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your requirement.

```
Sub test1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

        If Not ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then
            ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```